# Show that $[u]$ is a generator of $\pi(S^1,1)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Let $u:(I,\mathring I)\to(S^1,1)$ be the closed path $t\mapsto\exp(2\pi i t)$. Show that $[u]$ is a generator of $\pi(S^1,1)$.

I can see intuitively why this is true.

But I do not see how to prove it. Can someone give me hints?

What previous theorems should I use?

You can assume that I am familiar with all the previous theorems to this exercises. Which are all before page 54 from this book www.ugr.es/~acegarra/Rotman.pdf

(my apologies for not being clear)

Thank you

Comment: Have you deduced the fundamental group via covering spaces? If so, use them.

Comment: @ConnorMalin we have not defined covering spaces yet.

Comment: Do you mean $t \mapsto \exp(it)$? The proof is found any Algebraic Topology book. Check theorem 1.7 in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology.

Comment: @AymanHourieh I mean $t\mapsto\exp(t)=\exp(2\pi it)$. Thanks, in my book (Rotman) was proposed as an exercise.

Comment: Have a look at the mathoverflow discussion on https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40945/compelling-evidence-that-two-basepoints-are-better-than-one

Comment: I voted to close your question because it is missing context. The reader cannot know which methods are available to you (covering spaces, ...).

Comment: @PaulFrost You can assume that I am familiar with all the previous theorems to this exercises. Which are all before page 54 from this book http://www.ugr.es/~acegarra/Rotman.pdf

Comment: @AymanHourieh I did realize that the suggested proof use covering spaces.

Comment: @vino Then you should edit your question to include the information which textbook you use and which material is covered (in that case the fundamental group of $S^1$ is computed via use of the covering map $\exp : \mathbb R \to S^1$). Do not expect that the readers of your question want to read all comments. For future questions I strongly recommend that you provide all relevant facts and the background so that readers are not puzzled and do not have to ask for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Theorem 3.16 Rotman states that the degree function $\deg : \pi_1(S^1)  \to \mathbb Z$  is an isomorphism. The degree of your closed path $u$ is $1$ because the inclusion $i : [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ is the unique lifting of $u$ with $i(0) = 0$.

Hence $[u]$ is mapped to the generator $1$ of $\mathbb Z$ so that  $[u]$ is a generator of $\pi_1(S^1)$.

Comment: Thank you. (By the way, I think you meant Theorem 3.16)

Comment: You are right! I corrected  my answer.